# PowerMockito.mockStatic() of a static method is not working correctly in Spring Boot Test

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot

This is the setup of the test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = ServiceApplication.class)
@PrepareForTest({ MyClass.class })
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    public TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    public static MyClass myClass = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClassSetup() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class);
        BDDMockito.given(MyClass.getInstance(Mockito.anyString())).willReturn(myClass);
        BDDMockito.given(myClass.foo()).willReturn("BAR");
        // ...
    }
 .
 .
 .
 // test cases
```

In configuration class of this project, for load some beans, I use this static call for generate the instance.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "package.from.another.project.in.production" })
public class Beans {

    @Bean
    public MyClass myClass() {
        return MyClass.getInstance(K.FOO);
    }

}
```

This is my controller that uses the bean, as well as the static call according to the parameters.

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private MyClass myClass;

    @GetMapping(path = "/")
    public String doSomething() {
            String filter = myClass.foo();
            return filter;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/two")
    public String doSomething2(@RequestParam Map<String, String> allParams) {
            String accountId = allParams.get("account_id");
            String filter = MyClass.getInstance(K.BAR + accountId).foo();
            return filter;
    }
}
```

The bean is autowired because its use is greater than instantiation by the `getInstance()` method. In addition, the instantiation by the `getIntance()` method is variable according to the parameter. Don't ask me why the MyClass class is like this, because the API was old and I'm slowly refactoring.

The issue is that the autowired bean is correctly mocked by `PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class)` and also by `@MockBean` (which I used initially), but the call `MyClass.getInstance()` in `Controller.class` does not work at all.

I think the problem should happen when Spring climbs its environment and does not load everything that has been correctly mocked by PowerMockito, just the classes of its beans. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: This is just a wild guess, have you tried using regular Mockito as opposed to BDDMockito?  Just want to rule it out as a culprit.

Comment: Man, thanks, I didn't quite understand why, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a wild guess, have you tried using regular Mockito as opposed to BDDMockito? Just want to rule it out as a culprit.

Comment: Can you explain why? I accepted the question because it worked but you did not explain.

Comment: It was a wild guess.  I would call this a bug or that BDDMockito and Powermickito were not properly integrated.   It could be the case that POwermickito has code to work with Mockito specifically and would now need to change.  or it could be that BDDMockito has made changes to how it works in a way that breaks assumptions that PowerMickito was making.  Either way I am not involved in the development of these two projects.  How I arrived to this suggestion is based on years of troubleshooting.  Typically I revert back to a working state, which in my case was using Mockito vs BDDMockito.